# How to return multiple values from a single ternary operator?

Tags: c#, tuples, c#-7.0, c#-7.2

Let's say I have the following code:

```
int x    = GetBoolValue() ? 0 : 1;
string y = GetBoolValue() ? "foo" : "bar";
float z  = GetBoolValue() ? 0.4f : 0.5f;
```

Is there anyway to condense these three statements into one, to make the code simpler to read?

Answer (score 7):

Using C# 7 value tuples, you can do something like this:

```
var (x, y, z) = GetBoolValue() ? (0, "foo", 0.4f) : (1, "bar", 0.5f);
```

The `var` can be removed if they've already been declared and this will still work fine.